# Given 6 integers and 1 target value, write a function to get the target value using 6 integers with any on these operations ,*,-,/

Tags: java

Given 6 integers and 1 target value, write a function to get the target value using 6 integers with any on these operations +,*,-,/

This is what I did

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

int target =5;
int a[]={1,3,2,10,15,8};
int i,j;

for(j=0;j<6;j++)
for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    if(a[i]/a[j]==target)       System.out.println(a[i]+"/"+a[j]+"="+target);

for(j=0;j<6;j++)
for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    if(a[i]+a[j]==target)       System.out.println(a[i]+"+"+a[j]+"="+target);   


for(j=0;j<6;j++)
for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    if(a[i]*a[j]==target)       System.out.println(a[i]+"*"+a[j]+"="+target);

for(j=0;j<6;j++)
for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    if(a[i]-a[j]==target)       System.out.println(a[i]+"-"+a[j]+"="+target);

    }
}
```

I know this is wrong because I'm just using 1 operation at a time, what can I do to do multiple operations at once. For example, if it were a complex array like {45, 4, 84, 63, 91, 20, 400} and my target value was 455 which is (91*20)/4, then how can my program do that? How can it try all possible operations?

Comment: How would do you it with pen and paper?

Comment: I'm not sure, but if it is impossible, then maybe the question is use "any one operation" and I understood it wrong. You tell me, I'm not very good at coding.

Comment: No, you tell _us._ It's your question.

Comment: I don't know, if I had the solution on a paper, I would know how to implement it.

Comment: This question was allotted only 20minutes at an interview, but I can only think of a brute force approach. Store the result of all the single operations in different arrays. For example additionresultarray(a),m,d,s. Now, Multiply every element of a with every element of m and check result with target. Then divide that result with every element of d, and check with target. Then subtract. Next we will start with 'm' and start dividing, multiplying,subtracting(in all possible orders). This way we will have 4! steps.

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506264/checking-for-unique-output-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you're trying to write a solver for the [Countdown numbers game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countdown_%28game_show%29#Numbers_round).

It's not a trivial task, and you do generally end up with a 'brute-force' search running through many combinations.  I've written solvers for it before, but I'd struggle to write one in 20 minutes.

Here's some pseudocode that I hope illustrates the process.  I am assuming all of your numbers are positive:

```
// Assume numbers is sorted in ascending order
// progress_so_far lists the steps we have taken to get the solution.
void search(numbers, progress_so_far, target) {    
    for each a in numbers {
        for each b in numbers after a {
            for each op in + - * / {
                if (b op a is valid) {
                    result = b op a;

                    if (result == target) {
                       // Success !
                       // Print out how we got there.
                    }
                    else if (numbers.size() > 2) {
                        new_numbers = copy of numbers with a and b removed and result added, sorted in ascending order;
                        new_progress = copy of progress_so_far with 'b op a' added;
                        search(new_numbers, new_progress, target);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By `b op a is valid`, I mean that the calculation is not a subtraction resulting in zero or a division with a nonzero remainder.  As the numbers are sorted in ascending order and `b` comes after `a` in the list, `b` will be greater than or equal to `a`.  By making this restriction, we avoid duplicating effort thanks to the commutativity of `+` and `*` and ending up with negative numbers with `-`.

We can also check for and filter out 'useless' operations such as multiplying or dividing by 1, subtractions such as 8 - 4 (which 'wastes' the 8) or divisions such as 25 / 5 (which 'wastes' the 25).

Once you've found a target, you may want to keep going to see if you can hit the target using fewer steps.  It's possible that the first time a target is found there are redundant steps; by searching for the shortest you guarantee to remove these.

Comment: I think target should be new target, where target-=result;

Comment: @ChrisSu: why?  I don't see why it should.

Comment: search(new_numbers,new_progress,target). When you "tried" b op a, at this point, we don't know this op is valid or not, so we have to solve this recursively. Then the result should be updated. If not, the recursive will never find the result. That's my understanding of your code. Please let me know if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: @ChrisSu: the point is that the set of numbers that we search with is updated, not the target.  Suppose we have numbers 1, 3 and 5 with target 9.  If we choose to add together the 1 and 3, we then search recursively with the numbers 4 and 5, but we still have the target 9.